# How do I use optional segments inside an Outlet for a Tab routing result in Remix app?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I use default v2 routes convention and have reusable routes with optional segments such as:

- `staff.tsx`
- `$context.($id).info.tsx`
- `$context.($id).profile.tsx`

`staff.tsx` contains UI with Tabs and Outlet:

```
        <>
          <Tabs
            tabs={[
              { label: "Info", to: `info` },
              { label: "Profile", to: `profile` },
            ]}
          />
          <Outlet context={{ data }} />
        </>
```

Those segmented routes are not mounted inside the Outlet, but replace the whole `staff.tsx` UI when navigating. Is there something I am missing, or perhaps it is a limitation when using optional segments in navigation?

I am using `@remix-run` v2.3.0

I tried replacing optional segment routes with certain equivalents e.g. `$context.($id).profile.tsx` changed into `staff.profile.tsx`. It works when I am not using optional segments as expected, so profile is rendered inside the Outlet underneath the Tabs component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out the reason. I had routes defined in a given above manner e.g. `$context.($id).info.tsx`. The UI of routes with leading segments ($context) `staff` and `customers` differed so much, that I created  intermediate routes inside files called e.g. `customers.profile.tsx`. This lead to a mismatch and eventually to not rendering children routes such as `$context.($id).info.details.tsx` inside an `<Outlet/>`.

To sum up I changed `customers.profile.tsx` (which matches route pattern) to a `$context.($id).profile.tsx` and used conditional logic inside to render content for each of the contexts.